# Image of an ImageView to int Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Good friends, how can I pass the image of an `ImageView` to int in andrid studio to be able to save it in a BD, I load the image from a database in this way:

```
Intent intent = getIntent ();
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras ();

        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper adminPlants = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper (this, "Plants", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabasePlantsDatabase = PlantsPlants.getWritableDatabase ();

        Cursor file_plants = BaseDeDatosPlantas.rawQuery
                ("SELECT * from species where commonname = '" + b.getString ("name") + "'", null);
        if (file_plantas.moveToFirst ()) {
            tvNameE.setText (b.getString ("name"));
            tvSpeciesE.setText (file_plants.getString (2));
            tvDescripcionE.setText (file_plantas.getString (4));
            imgFotoE.setImageResource (file_plantas.getInt (5)); // Here I send the image to the ImageView
        }
        PlantsDatabase.close ();
```

In the app, the image is changed for another on the device, now as I do the opposite, get the image from the `ImageView` and pass it to an int and thus be able to save it in BD again.

```
public void SaveE (View view) {
        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper (this, "Plants", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase DataBase = admin.getWritableDatabase ();
        
        Database.execSQL ("update species set description = '" + tvDescripcionE.getText () + "', photo =" + imageResource
                + "where CommonName = '" + tvNameE.getText () + "';"); // This is where I need the int of the image
        Database.close ();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As `ImageView` can host any type of `Drawable`, not just one specified by a resource id, there's no API to get the resource id back *out* of the ImageView.

That said, you could always save the resource id to the ImageView as a `tag` when you assign it:

```
int resourceId = file_plantas.getInt (5);
imgFotoE.setImageResource (resourceId);
imgFotoE.setTag(resourceId);
```

And then you could retrieve it later:

```
int resourceId = (int) imgFotoE.getTag();
```

Comment: And if the image is loaded from the device and from there the image is loaded into a database, how could it be possible?